# How to get value from anchor tag in html from php

Tags: php, html

```html
<button type="submit" name="type" value="Pizza1">Submit</button>
<a id="cart" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('sa').submit();" name="type" value="Pizza1" class="cart">Add to cart</a>
```

I want to send the value from anchor tag to the php file but it is only successful if I click submit button not by anchor tag.

```php
$types=$_GET['type'];
```

Comment: what you exactly want to perform?

Comment: well i want to send a type of pizza that user is selecting to my php file so that i can later send it to database

Comment: you can use this pattern

`<button type="submit" name="type" value="Pizza1" onclick="window.open('http://www.example.com/?type=pizza1,'_self')">Submit</button>`

Comment: Links are not submit buttons. Instead of writing masses of JS to make a link act like a submit button: Use a submit button. (And apply CSS to make it look the way you want).

Answer (score 0):

By default an anchor tag would just do a GET so I think you need to modify the href of the anchor to add the value to the URL.

If you were using JQuery you could do something like

> $('#cart').attr('href','?value=' + $('#cart').attr('value'))

to modify the URL. You should then be able to access this in your server side code.